# Parsing local file

Tags: c#, json, parsing, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I want to parse from local file (.txt) And I get this. Can anybody help?

I use Visual Studio 2012 and make win8 app using Grid template.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll

WinRT information: Invalid character at position 1063.

Additional information: Invalid JSON string.

App.xaml.cs:

```
      protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;



        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            //Associate the frame with a SuspensionManager key                                
            SuspensionManager.RegisterFrame(rootFrame, "AppFrame");

            if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                // Restore the saved session state only when appropriate
                try
                {

                    await SuspensionManager.RestoreAsync();
                }
                catch (SuspensionManagerException)
                {


                }
            }

            if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
            {

                Window.Current.Activate();
            }

            await VitsitDataSource.LoadLocalDataAsync();

                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(GroupedItemsPage), "AllGroups"))
            {

                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
        }
        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

Comment: The code you posted seems completly unrelated to your problem. What does your GroupedItemsPage do when you navigate to it?

Comment: I get this when i try debug, but designer GroupedItemsPage seems wine, but items not showing.. Errors list is clear..

Comment: System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw  00000000  push        esi 
00000001  mov         esi,ecx 
00000003  mov         ecx,dword ptr [esi+4] 
00000006  mov         edx,esi 
00000008  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx 
0000000a  call        FF98289C 
0000000f  mov         ecx,dword ptr [esi+4] 
00000012  call        FF888908 
00000017  int         3

Comment: Based on the error your `.txt.7 file contains a JSON string? How are your aprsing it? Can you show some code? Have you checked your file (at position 1063)?